# Asp.net core + IIS Express. How to view log messages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I'm trying to print a log message in ASP.NET Core this way:

```
Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!" );

loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
loggerFactory.AddConsole( LogLevel.Debug );
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");
logger.LogWarning( "Hi!" );
```

Where can I see this message?

The Output window doesn't contain this message.

If I run the project as Web, it runs the `dnx` console where I can see the message, but it is not convenient.

If I run project as IIS Express I don't see the console, or the message.

Is there way to view the message in Visual Studio?

Comment: This is a really old question, but I stumbled upon it today. I hope my answer helps future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Debug` listener](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug) to achieve what you want:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

---

```
Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!" );

loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
loggerFactory.AddDebug( LogLevel.Debug );
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");
logger.LogWarning( "Hi!" );
```

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. There are providers which provide output to different output streams.

Comment: Very helpful; to add some context: the JSON snippet must be integrated into file `project.json`, and the C# snippet typically into the `Config()` method of class `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 9):

None of the other answers addresses the actual question: "How can we see those messages when running the project with IIS Express?". So, I decided to add my own, I hope it helps somebody.

The usual console window does not show up when you choose IIS Express. But you can still see those messages by following the below steps.

1. Look for the `Output` window in Visual Studio. If you already have it, skip the next step
2. Goto View-menu > Output or press `Ctrl + W,O`. The output window will show up.
3. In the output window, change the dropdown to *"<-your-project-name-> ASP.NET Core Web Server"* or something similar.
4. You should be able to see those messages here.

[image]

I am using VS 2019, the above steps can differ based on your IDE version.

Comment: This is correct. Don't be confused by the "Show output from" dropdown where it says "ASP.Net Core Web Server"...you still select that when you 're using IIS Express. Also, if you want to log all requests, even without using the "logger" in .Net, modify the default appsettings.Development.json file that's automatically created, and change the value for "Microsoft" under "LogLevel" from "Warning" to "Information".

Answer (score 4):

IIS Express will not output its logs to Visual Studio's output window.

You'll need to use a different log provider.

Write it to a log file. You can use a library for that, for example [Serilog](http://nblumhardt.com/2015/05/diagnostic-logging-in-dnx-asp-net-5/):

```
using Serilog;

public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
          .CreateLogger();
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

You'll need [this NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/1.0.0-rc1-final-10092) package.

Comment: It's bad. Even NetBeans could show Glass Fish logs. Maybe there is plugin to connet VS to IIS Express?

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Documents** => **IISExpress** => **Logs**.

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean file.log or Visual Studio Window?
I found logs in C:\Users\User-Name\Documents\IISExpress\Logs\Site\*.log but even there I don't see my messages.

Comment: What you're pointing to are the _IIS Express_ logs, not what the user code logs.